# Difference between methods to read a byte from TCP server?

Tags: java, android, tcpclient

Im trying to read information sent for a client on android using the TCP protocol. In my server I have this code:

```
InputStream input = clienteSocket.getInputStream();
int c = input.read();
```

c will containt the ascci number that the client send.

I also can get this by writing:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

I would like to know what is the difference between both methods.

Comment: Do you only need _a_ (single) byte from the client or everything that's in the stream?

Comment: (a) Define 'best'. (b) You do realize that one gives you a byte, the other a char? (c) You've mixed up 'from client' and 'from server', not that it makes the slightest difference.

Answer (score 1):

The buffered approach is better because (in most cases) reduces the number of syscalls that the JVM needs to make to the operating system.  Since syscalls are relatively expensive, buffering *generally* gives you better performance.

---

In your specific example:

- Each time you call `c.read()` on an input stream you do a syscall.
- The first time you do a `c.read()` (or other read operation) on a buffered input stream, it reads a number of bytes into an in-memory byte-array.  In second, third, etc calls to `c.read()`, the read will typically return a byte out of the in-memory buffer, without making a syscall.

In your example, the only case where using a buffered stream doesn't help would be if you are going to read only one byte from the socket, and then close it.

---

**UPDATE**

I didn't notice that you were comparing an unbuffered `InputStream` with a buffered >> `Reader` <<.  As @EJP, points out, this is "comparing Apples and Oranges".  The functionality of the two versions is different.  One reades bytes and the other reads characters.

(And if you don't understand *that* distinction ... and why it is an **important** distinction ... you would be advised to read the Java Tutorial lesson on [Basic I/O](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).  Particularly the sections on byte streams, character streams and buffered streams.)

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing apples and oranges here.

- Your first example reads one byte from the stream, unbuffered, and returns the value of that byte. (Adding 'ASCII number' to that adds no actual information.)
- Your second example sets up a buffered reader, which *can* read chars from the stream, buffered, but it doesn't actually read anything.

You could set up two further examples:

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
int c = is.read();
```

This reads a byte, with buffering.

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream();
int c = reader.read();
```

This reads a char, with a little buffering: not as much as `BufferedReader` provides.

The realistic choices are between the two buffered versions, for efficiency reasons as outlined by @StephenC, and the choice between them is dictated by whether you want bytes or chars.